# Mysql JSON_ARRAYAGG from another table in select

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have vacancies and departments and I want to get all departments with vacancies as json array. I try to use JSON_ARRAYAGG function but got mysql syntax error.

```
select vd.id, vd.title, vd.sort,
(select json_arrayagg(v.id, v.title) from vacancies as v where vd.id = v.department_id) as vacancies
from vacancy_departments as vd
```

Comment: 1) Pls share the exact syntax error, the `near …` part contains an important clue as to what may have caused the error. 2) Also, what's the exact version of your MySQL? This function was introduced in 5.7.22.

Comment: The function [JSON_ARRAYAGG()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg) should be used with 1 parameter only

Answer (score 1):

If you provided some sample data and an expected outcome we could have a better go for you. Try something like this in the meantime:

```
SELECT vd.id, vd.title, vd.sort,
(
    SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
        JSON_MERGE_PRESERVE(
            JSON_OBJECT("id", v.id),
            JSON_OBJECT("title", v.title)
            ))
    FROM vacancies as v
    WHERE vd.id = v.department_id
) as vacancies
FROM vacancy_departments as vd
```